# SQL Exception when inserting HTML to SQL Server

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have a trouble ,when storing HTML code to SQL Server.

I get a general exception when trying to insert the following code:

```html
<html>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0 border=0 style='background:#f6f6f6; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;'>
</body>
</html>
```

> Can anyone explain why this would throw an error?

Save Full html code as a string parameter and send to SQL.
I know HTML can be stored in SQL, just like a string, but this is causing me issues.

My sql code is :

```
insert into UserTemplate (FullCode) values (N'    <html>
    <title>test</title>
    <body>
    <table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0 border=0 style='background:#f6f6f6; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;'>
    </body>
    </html>')
```

and error is :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near
>   'background:'.

I found the problem and solved it by adding a **comma**. But HTML code changes according to user registration and edit theme and data. I need a more sophisticated storage mode to store my personal templates in the database. And don't face these mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: There is the possibility that you haven't escaped the necessary characters, but without the actual insert statement, and the error, it's just guessing.

Comment: Please include the exact exception message when you ask a question about a SQL Exception.

Comment: Show SQL insert statement.  Pure guesswork otherwise.  But it's probably the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The quote is causing the problem. Insert 'this '' text' will insert a quote into a char column.

Answer (score 0):

You can sanitize special characters from your html on client side by using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Sql Server detects these kind of characters as a threat for [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: SQL Server doesn't do any threat detection for SQL injection.